# Overflow: hidden isn't working consistently

Tags: html, overflow, css

I am working on some buttons. I want to have a rollover state and I have this in an image in a div with overflow:hidden to hide the state that's not active. It works sometimes but sometimes it looks like this:

[image: Broken]

The weirdest part is that when I try to use the Chrome Web Inspector it fixes itself! And nothing looks weird in the HTML/CSS.

[image: Working]

I'm super confused as to why it isn't consistently either broken or working.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="hunting_card_button">
    <div class="hunting_card_icon" id="gift_to_friend">
        <img src="/images/icons/friend2.png?1" />
    </div>
    Friend
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.hunting_card_button {
    width: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
.hunting_card_icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
.hunting_card_icon:hover {
    right: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you're doing the rollover? Is it js or css?

Comment: Edited it in, CSS. We're also doing some JS to work with the states of these buttons but that's only executed on-click so it shouldn't come into play since this is acting up on page-load.

Comment: There must be something else going on. I tried to replicate your issue with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zaTMh/3/ 
but I can't repro...

Comment: I'm not completely sure if it's fixed but after adding position: relative to .hunting_card_button I haven't encountered it again. I'm hesitant to say it's fixed since it was intermittent to start with and I don't understand why this would have fixed it. But for now it's not manifesting itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change one of its containers to a div from a span.